# Totient Function: if $\gcd(m,n)=2$, then $\varphi{(mn)}=2\varphi{(m)}\varphi{(n)}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, self-learning, totient-function

Suppose we know that $(m,n)=2$.  Show that this implies that $\phi{(mn)}=2\phi{(m)}\phi{(n)}$.

My attempt:

So let $m=p_1^{r_1}p_2^{r_2}...p_k^{r_k}, n=p_1^{s_1}p_2^{s_2}...p_k^{s_k}$.  Then
$(m,n)=p_1^{\min{(r_1,s_1)}}p_2^{\min{(r_2,s_2)}}...p_k^{\min{(r_k,s_k)}}=2$, So $p_1=2$ and $\min{(r_1,s_1)}=1$ and for all other $\min{(r_i,s_i)}=0$.

This means that $m$ and $n$ differ in their prime decomposition for all primes $p_j$ except $p_1=2$.

How to finish?  I'm almost there I feel like and I just need the next argument...hints would be appreciated...

Comment: Write $n = 2^a\cdot \nu;\; m = 2^b\cdot \mu$. Alternatively, use that $$\varphi(k) = k\cdot \prod_{p\mid k} \left(1 - \frac{1}{p}\right).$$

Comment: That works for me... Thanks.

Comment: In fact, the statement may be generalized. If $(m,n)=p$, where $p$ is prime, then $\phi (mn)/\phi (m)\phi (n)=p/p-1$.

Comment: Thanks Rodney...the next example i did was exactly the case where $(m,n)=p$